# How to join two table for search on base of primary and foreign key?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have two table one is **table1**

id    name   price

1      name1   100

2      name2   200

**table2**

id    authorityId   agency   start_date end_date

1     1           agency1   1-2-2015   2-12015

I want to search the value in second table which working fine for me
but  I want the name from the first table on the basis of foreign key(table1_id) .How I can do this.Any help will be appreciated?

This is my code

Controller:

```
public function searchResult()
{

    $search_term = array(
    'authorityId' => $this->input->get('authority'),
    'grantVillage' => $this->input->get('village'),
    'startDate' => $this->input->get('startDate'),
    'endDate' => $this->input->get('endDate'));
    //print_r($search_term);
    $data['searchResult'] = $this->grant_model->searchResult($search_term);
    $this->load->view('searchResult',$data);

}
```

Model:

```
 public function searchResult($search_term)
    {
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('grant_data');
           $this->db->like('authorityId', $search_term['authorityId']);
           $this->db->like('grantVillage', $search_term['grantVillage']);
           $this->db->like('startDate', $search_term['startDate']);
           $this->db->like('certificate', $search_term['certificate']);
           $this->db->like('endDate', $search_term['endDate']);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use like that --

```
   $this -> db -> select('*');
   $this -> db -> from('table2');
   $this->db->join('table1','table1.table1_id = table2.autority_id');
   $this -> db -> where('table2'.'id', 5);
   $query = $this -> db -> get();
   return $query->result_array();
```

it will get both table data try it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This will work fine if user will select the autority_id(name) in the search field.If user will not select the autority_id so how I can do that.Because I have four field in the search.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function searchResult($search_term)
    {
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('grant_data');
           $this->db->like('authorityId', $search_term['authorityId']);
           $this->db->like('grantVillage', $search_term['grantVillage']);
           $this->db->like('startDate', $search_term['startDate']);
           $this->db->like('certificate', $search_term['certificate']);
           $this->db->like('endDate', $search_term['endDate']);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           return $query->result();
    }
```

After running this query result is

id        foreign_key    field1    field2     field3

now I want the name from another table on the basis of foreign_key

How I can I do this?